Python: Cluster Model Based on Likely Seasonal Data
I have a dataset that looks like the following:

ID YR-MONTH X1
1 2021-01 100
1 2021-02 200
1 2021-03 12
2 2021-01 150
2 2021-03 10

The data is likely seasonal; in Dec/Jan/Feb and in Jul/Aug/Sep I expect the regressor X1 to be different (larger, relative to an individual ID's time series, for some ID's, maybe smaller for other IDs). Also, if a month is not present for an ID, then the X1 should be set to 0.
Is there a cluster-based model which can be coded in Python that should be able to identify seasonal trends like this? To cluster each ID into batches based on whether X1 spikes up or depresses on certain months.
I tried using tslearn.clustering > TimeSeriesKMeans and TimeSeriesScalerMeanVariance,  but it does not cluster based on seasonal ID's, but rather forms its own clusters... essentially, the clusters were ID's with higher values of X1, and those with lower values.

Maybe this will help ^^
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# Assuming your data is stored in a DataFrame called df
# Preprocessing
df['YR-MONTH'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YR-MONTH'])
df = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='YR-MONTH', values='X1').fillna(0)

# Feature Engineering - calculate mean for each quarter
quarterly_mean = df.resample('Q', axis=1).mean()

# Scale the features
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_features = scaler.fit_transform(quarterly_mean)

# Clustering
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)  # You can adjust the number of clusters
clusters = kmeans.fit_predict(scaled_features)

# Add cluster labels back to the DataFrame
df['Cluster'] = clusters

# Visualize or analyze the clusters

